# jQuery AJAX - Unexpected token + parsererror

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, parse-error

I wrote a script using jQuery and AJAX  today, and I get some errors...

The script:

```
function changeAdmin(id) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ta-modarea-'+id).fadeOut('fast');
    $('#ta-m-loading-'+id).fadeIn('fast');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_utf.php?a=changeteamadmin',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            admin : $('#admin-id-'+id).val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#ta-m-loading-'+id).fadeOut('fast');
            $('#ta-modarea-'+id).text(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#ta-m-loading-'+id).fadeOut('fast');
            $('#ta-modarea-'+id).text('HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error Message: '+textStatus).fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
}
```

After the run, I get this error message: `HTTP Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < | Error Message: parsererror`

Could you help me, what should I do?

Comment: What happens if you call ajax_utf.php?a=changeteamadmin directly outside of your javascript?

Comment: It shows a message what I sat up in the PHP file.

Comment: can you check if the json returned is valid? you can check at www.jsonlint.com

Comment: It doesn't like jQuery codes .. :(

Answer (score 7):

You need to send an `application/json` header via PHP , like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

That's because jQuery sends an Accept header (`application/json, text/javascript`), and this is the cause of `parseerror` triggered by `jqXHR`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to solve this problem in **asp.net** ?

Comment: To solve this is ASP.NET (webforms) you can add the `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` attribute to your method.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 alert( jqXHR.responseText);
```

in your error function

Comment: it says: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: I think ajax_utf.php return html code and not json. Do you use json_encode() in youp php script?

Comment: and maybe you also echo html code during the execution of the script?
Does your php scrit include any html tags?

Comment: Yes. Now I found, I made a new php, with only this one code. Now I don't get error, but I don't get any response to my site.
The javascript code: "$('#ta-modarea-'+id).text(data.msg).fadeIn('fast');"

And the PHP:
$return['msg'] = 'something here';
echo json_encode($return);

Comment: Try to alert(data.msg),
also try to add changeteamadmin to the data:
{
a: 'changeteamadmin',
admin : $('#admin-id-'+id).val()
}

Comment: and dont forget in you php script: if ($_POST['a'] == 'changeteamadmin') { ..... }

Comment: I tried some things. It has problem with an IF.

From the "PROBLEM FROM HERE"

if (empty($_POST['admin'])) {
   $return['msg'] = 'Hibás GAMER ID.';
  } else {
   $do->mysqlSelect('user', 'icl_users', 'WHERE id = "'.$_POST['admin'].'" LIMIT 1');
   $user_nr = $do->msS('user', 'nr');
   $user_team = $do->msS('user', 'team_id');
   if ($user_nr == 0) {
    $return['msg'] = 'Hibás GAMER ID.';
   } else {
    //PROBLEM FROM HERE
    if ($user_nr == 0) {
     $return['msg'] = 'Módosítás sikeres.';
    } else {
     $return['msg'] = 'A felhasználó már egy másik csapatban van.';
    }
   }
  }

Comment: I don't know what type of problem do you have, but if your php version is 5.4.0 , you can try to add JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE:
echo json_encode($return,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: I have 5.3.5. Could you find the problem, if I send you the source files?

Comment: before the line "if (empty($_POST['admin'])) {", try to add "$return['msg'] = "";"

Comment: and also change if ($_GET['a'] == 'changeteamadmin') { --- to if ($_POST['a'] == 'changeteamadmin') {

Comment: sorry, no change, still no response. :(

Comment: so in the ajax data, change the
a : 'changeadmin',    to --------- a : 'changeteamadmin',

Comment: I've changed before trying to run it

Comment: Or could you show or write me a working one for jQuery, and I'll change it for myself.

Comment: I got same problem in MVC ajax call. Problem waw path to controller was not exact.

Answer (score 2):

If you have tried setting the header content type and are still getting the error. It is my expectation that the server is replying with a fault from your server side code.  Usually when a debug message is given it is in pure HTML not JSON thus the unexpected token.

The quickest way to debug this is to set the DataType of the HTML instead of JSON so that you can see whatever output there is from the server, not just JSON formatted data.

Once you have seen the error that is being produced by your server side code and fixed it, you can then return to being a DataType  of JSON.

Answer (score 1):

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Answer (score 1):

Try code below, but if you receive an error like "Unexpected token <", you need to check your php file - "ajax_utf.php" and check what is returned in browser (Chrome) View->Developer->Developer Tools, Network tab -> XHR.

[image]

```
         $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: postLink,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: postData,

            beforeSend: function (x) {
                if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                    x.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=UTF-8' );
                }
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with missmatching PHP associative/numeric arrays and Javascript objects.

Try this:

```
$data = new Array();
$data['test'][] = "Row 1";
$data['test'][] = "Row 2";
echo json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

This should force json encoder to always encode to objects instead of numeric arrays and may solve the problem.